# What's the url of the user stats site of SO again?

Tags: support, statistics

I just had the URL of a nice "Query Interface" where you could find so many interesting things about user rep by tags, by time, etc., and now I can't find it again. What's the URL for that site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's http://odata.stackexchange.com/.

And in case you forget about it again in the future, you can find it in the footer as the **Data** link.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the footer. I just forgot that, now I know why did not bookmark it :)